# How does Maven avoid race conditions in the local repository?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

On a large Linux server, I want to run 8 independent instances of Jenkins on different ports. However, the instances will all run as user "jenkins", and the jenkins user has its maven repository in /home/jenkins/.m2/repository.

My understanding of maven is that it is designed for a single user; in other words, maven has no concept of simultaneous maven builds. So as these 8 jenkins instances churn away building maven projects and reading from/writing to /home/jenkins/.m2/repository, how does maven protect itself from race conditions?

Thanks.

Comment: Why you don't want to run single jenkins instance with several build workers in it? It is general way of jenkins using on my mind.

Comment: There is 'use private Maven repository' option in build configuration in Jenkins, would that help ?

Comment: Why 8 separate Jenkins instances instead of one instance and 8 jobs? Then I think you can make one job depend on the completion of another so that they run in the right order.

Comment: @kuporific We have 8 large development teams currently using 1 Jenkins instance, so we have 1200 jenkins jobs on 1 jenkins. We want to break that up into 1 Jenkins instance per team.

Answer (score 1):

In Jenkins you can defined executors which is more or less equivalent to the cores you have on the machine. Furthermore you can define each job having its own repository by activating the `use private Maven repository` option which is the default to separate those jobs from each other. This will make the maven repository local to the appropriate workspace. So each job has its own workspace you have separate repositories for each job. Result. No Problem.

**Update:**

If you use a single repository for several builds (does not matter if in Jenkins or on command line) those builds are no longer **independent**. It does not matter if the functionality has been synchronized in any way.

Comment: Thanks. We have 8 large development teams currently using 1 Jenkins instance, so we have 1200 jenkins jobs on 1 jenkins. We want to break that up into 1 Jenkins instance per team. So 8 Jenkinses, all with a reasonable 100 to 150 jobs each. But we don't want private repos in every workspace of every job. That would be 100 to 150 local maven repos.

Comment: You can clean the workspace after each build with post build task if hdd space is the reason you don't want private repos.

Comment: @pvytykac Thanks. Ignore Jenkins for the moment. The original question is does maven have race conditions if run concurrently, and I am using Jenkins as the initiator. But maven could also be run concurrently at the Linux command line. If maven does not have race conditions, then running multiple Jenkinses as one user will be fine. The main question is the maven question.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the local repo between multiple Jenkins jobs is not safe. Parallel builds using same artefacts often fail with random NullPointer/IO exceptions.

Following 2 issues contain some additional info, and it seems from the comments that its not something they will be fixing:

- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MINSTALL-54
- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MINVOKER-104

**Parallel builds**

> This build-mode analyzes your project's dependency graph and schedules modules that can be built in parallel according to the dependency graph of your project.

Since version 3, there is **experimental** 'Parallel builds' feature in maven, so there has to be some kind of synchronization. But I assume it synchronizes the access to maven-metadata-local.xml file in JVM not globally. Additionally it only takes care of building sub-modules of the parent pom in parallel.

**Workarround:**

To my knowledge the only way to prevent this is to have private local repo per jenkins build. If its undesired to have the local repos stored on hdd you can clean them after the build with post build task.

Comment: The parallel build feature is not `experimental` and has never been. It was a new feature which has been introduced with Maven 3. Maven 3 started at 2010 in the meantime we have 2015 isn't it matured enough. Apart from that it has proven that i works perfectly. Furthermore if you share such repository the result is that your builds are no longer independent from each other.